# Upload an image in OpenCV using the pointe

Tags: c++, opencv, c++14

Question: How to upload an image in OpenCV using the pointer.

Input: Pointer to image

Required Output: cv::Mat image

Explanation: you can do this (below) if the picture is in a directory;

```
String imageName("C:/Images/1.jpg");
Mat image;
image = imread(samples::findFile(imageName), IMREAD_COLOR);
```

I try to get the same, but using pointer.

Thank you in advance for your attention to my question :)

Comment: What are you referring to by "pointer to Image" what is the type: a pointer to a `Mat`? a pointer to a `String` containing the image path? some other type?

Comment: pointer to bytes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few `cv::Mat` constructors, that create/initialize matrix headers for already existing user data, e.g. [this](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a51615ebf17a64c968df0bf49b4de6a3a):

```cpp
cv::Mat::Mat(int rows, int cols, int type, void* data, size_t step = AUTO_STEP)
```

Please see the given link for the complete parameter description. Nevertheless, regarding the user data `data`, you must pay attention to the following:

> Pointer to the user data. Matrix constructors that take data and step parameters **do not allocate matrix data**. Instead, they just initialize the matrix header that points to the specified data, which means that **no data is copied**. This operation is very efficient and can be used to process external data using OpenCV functions. **The external data is not automatically deallocated, so you should take care of it.**

A very small example is given by this code snippet:

```cpp
// Set up byte array: 3 rows, 3 columns, BGR values.
uint8_t data[3][3][3] = {
    {
        { 100, 110, 120 },      // row 0, col 0, BGR
        { 130, 140, 150 },      // row 0, col 1, BGR
        { 160, 170, 180 }       // row 0, col 2, BGR
    },
    {
        { 190, 200, 210 },      // row 1, col 0, BGR
        { 220, 230, 240 },      // row 1, col 1, BGR
        { 100, 120, 140 }       // row 1, col 2, BGR
    },
    {
        { 160, 180, 200 },      // row 2, col 0, BGR
        { 100, 130, 160 },      // row 2, col 1, BGR
        { 190, 220, 250 }       // row 2, col 2, BGR
    },
};

// Create cv::Mat header pointing to the image data.
cv::Mat image = Mat(3, 3, CV_8UC3, *data);
```

Inspecting `image` at runtime (here: Visual Studio, Image Watch) shows a proper result:

[image: Output]